# Select one way without return

Tags: postgresql, copy, sql-delete, resultset, journey

Working with the professional mobility of insee on more than 1m of entities, i seek to add up a field called ipondi only on the journeys from commune of residence to commune of work, and not of commune of work to residential commune.

Let us assume a simple example, with the column of commune of residence named "departure", and commune of work named "arrival", and the field which i wish to make the sum named "ipondi":

```
start; end; ipondi
La Ciotat; Marseille; 84
La Ciotat; Marseille; 15
Aubagne; Ceyreste; 12
Marseille; La Ciotat; 73
```

So I get the following result:

```
select start, end, sum(ipondi)
from trajets
group by start, end
```

So I get the following result:

```
La Ciotat; Marseille; 99
Aubagne; Ceyreste; 12
Marseille; La Ciotat; 73
```

Which is normal. However, I would like to "delete" the Marseille; La Ciotat because it is the return journey of the first two lines. 
This being so to arrive at this result:

```
start; end; ipondi
La Ciotat; Marseille; 99
Aubagne; Ceyreste; 12
```

My link to my database :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOB1MTAt8UNCjt0up6qcgnR593yMXkqt/view?usp=sharing

How to do this on PostgreSQL?

Thank you.

Comment: How can we distinguish the way in from the return journey?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Let's say I would take the line with the highest Ipondi value for the go value. In this case, between La Ciotat; Marseille; 99 and Marseille; La Ciotat; 73, i keep La Ciotat; Marseille; 99